# Access cloud machines by name

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, google-compute-engine, nameserver

I have production machines on Google Cloud and Amazon. On both clouds, I have common server on each called monitoring which has public ip. Through these monitoring machines, I access all machines on respective clouds. However, the problem is I have to access them like `ssh -i abc.pem user@<ip address>`  instead I wish to access them like `ssh -i abc.pem user@<machine name>`
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS.

Easy to insert into your organization's DNS `monitoring.gcp.example.net` and `monitoring.aws.example.net`

Answer (score 0):

@JohnMahowald's answer is the correct one if your solution has to scale to a group of people who all need convenient access to your cloud instances.

But if it's only you, and/or you can't get your DNS admin to co-operate with your request, there are other avenues you can explore.

If convenient ssh access is all you need, your `~/.ssh/config` file is your friend.

```
$ cat << EOF >> ~/.ssh/config
Host machine_name
  Hostname ip.addr.of.machine
  User remote_username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/abc.pem

EOF
```

With that stanza in your `~/.ssh/config` file, when you issue the command:

```
$ ssh machine_name
```

`ssh` will use the IP address given as `ip.addr.of.machine` and the remote username `remote_username` to connect to that host.

Your `/etc/hosts` file could also stand as a substitute for an actual DNS entry, such as if there's a web page or SNMP agent at that address that you want to query.  But again, that's probably effective only if a very small number of people require convenient access.

The `.ssh/config` solution is highly configurable, if ssh access is all you need.  And even if you *do* have a DNS entry for your host, you can still use a shorter, easier-to-type nickname in the `Host` line, and put the DNS name in the `Hostname` line.

```
Host gcp
    Hostname monitoring.gcp.example.net
    User gcp_username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/abc.pem

Host aws
    Hostname monitoring.aws.example.net
    User aws_username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/abc.pem
```

With those `config` entries you can just:

```
$ ssh gcp
```

or

```
$ ssh aws
```

to log in to either instance, using the correct username per instance, and without having to remember which identity key to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. ~/.ssh/config solved my problem. :-)